# Plotly: Categorial colouring with varying levels of intensity based on attribute

Tags: python, plot, plotly

To give a simple example, say that I have footballers in a 2D scatterplot. These are in one of three groups: A, B, C.

```
A = Red color
B = Blue color
C = Green color
```

Now comes the complicated part:
Say that each footballer has an attribute “goals scored”. The more goals scored, the darker the color I want. So for example, if a player on team A has scored 10 goals then the red colour should be darker then for a player on team A with only 4 goals scored.

Is this possible?

This is the skeleton code of the scatter that someone asked for:

```
traces.append(go.Scatter(
                    x=X,
                    y=Y,
                    text=feature,           
                    mode='markers',
                    opacity=0.7,
                    marker={'size': 15,
                            'line': {'width': 0.5,
                                     'color': 'white'}},
                    name=feature))
```

Thank you!

Comment: You missed the part where you attempt to solve the problem yourself and attach the partially working code, so that others can look into the problem and help you!!!!

Comment: @NarenMurali Wow, That is a lot of explanation marks. Very impressive. 
There are better ways to let me know if you feel that I missed something.
But I will add some code.. that does not work then.

Comment: it was not written in an offensive tone, just reminding that some people want to help and not to provide the whole code from scratch for free!

Comment: You're new so I didn't downvote but I should have. [Reason 1 - no research](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/),  [Reason 2 - no code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/)

Answer (score 0):

This is possible by passing the scatter a `color` as found [here](https://plot.ly/python/colorscales/) in the documentation.

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

data = [
    go.Scatter(
        y=[5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5],
        marker=dict(
            size=16,
            cmax=39,
            cmin=0,
            color=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39],
            colorbar=dict(
                title='Colorbar'
            ),
            colorscale='Viridis'
        ),
        mode='markers')
]

fig = go.Figure(data=data)
iplot(fig)
```

There are a few built in `colorscale` [options](https://community.plot.ly/t/what-colorscales-are-available-in-plotly-and-which-are-the-default/2079/2):

> 'Blackbody', 'Bluered', 'Blues', 'Earth', 'Electric', 'Greens', 'Greys’, 'Hot', 'Jet', 'Picnic', 'Portland', 'Rainbow', 'RdBu', 'Reds', 'Viridis', 'YlGnBu', 'YlOrRd'

You also have the ability to create your own colorscale. As per the [documentation](https://plot.ly/python/reference/#scatter-marker-colorscale):

> Sets the colorscale and only has an effect if `marker.color` is set to a numerical array. The colorscale must be an array containing arrays mapping a normalized value to an rgb, rgba, hex, hsl, hsv, or named color string. At minimum, a mapping for the lowest (0) and highest (1) values are required. For example, `[[0, 'rgb(0,0,255)', [1, 'rgb(255,0,0)']]`. To control the bounds of the colorscale in color space, use `marker.cmin` and `marker.cmax`. Alternatively, `colorscale` may be a palette name string of the following list: Greys, YlGnBu, Greens, YlOrRd, Bluered, RdBu, Reds, Blues, Picnic, Rainbow, Portland, Jet, Hot, Blackbody, Earth, Electric, Viridis, Cividis

[image]

Comment: Thank you!
But here I only see one grouping: 'Viridis'. 
I would ideally want three (or more) different groups. And then each point is a different colour intensity of one group.

Comment: @KimO See updates. Please research your questions before hand, these are all coming straight from the Plot.ly documentation on their page.